# Magento 2 error in swatchRenderer.js

Tags: javascript, magento2

I have overridden magento `SwatchRenderer.js` file in `app\code\Mydirectory\CustomSwatches\view\frontend\web\js\SwatchRenderer.js`.

My problem is I get an error in my product page load:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateData' of undefined

I found out that `data('gallery')` on `SwatchRenderer.js`'s following function is undefined.

```
updateBaseImage: function (images, context, isProductViewExist) {
        var justAnImage = images[0];

        if (isProductViewExist) {
            context
                .find('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]')
                .data('gallery')
                .updateData(images);
        } else if (justAnImage && justAnImage.img) {
            context.find('.product-image-photo').attr('src', justAnImage.img);
        }
    }
```

I checked a Magento 2 demo site. On that site the above data attribute is set as a JavaScript object. The target element is a div with the above attribute. But in my site it is undefined and obviously I think that data attribute is not set on my site. Can anyone help me to find the setter function/view/file for above element? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What theme was used in your Magento instance? Did you rename the container class names?

One interesting piece of code is found on line 202 of the SwatchRenderer.js file. Under the _create function you will find the initialization of the gallery variable as seen [here](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1459486734.png)

You will notice that it finds the element with the data-gallery under the .column.main element. Thus, as missing column main element would return an empty response.

Comment: What theme was used in your Magento instance? Did you rename the container class names?
A custom theme and no, I didn't rename the container classes. They are in the appropriate places.

The element `[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]` is there. But it is missing the `data-gallery` (not `data-gallery-role`) attribute.

Comment: just SwatchRenderer file?

Comment: Your HTML code for the product view page.

You may also try executing jQuery("[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]") on your browser console to check if the said element is existing on the product view page.

Next, try executing jQuery("[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]",".column.main") if the element does exists.

Please post the results of the above jQuery codes for me to explain further the solution to your problem

Comment: @oliver I did those experiments but it failed. `<div class="media-gallery" data-role="media-gallery"><div class="zoom-image"><a href="<?php echo $large; ?>" data-role="gallery-thumb"> <img src="<?php echo $medium; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName();?>" title="<?php echo $product->getName();?>"/> </a>  </div>`

Comment: The code above is my data role in Magento default, should I rename it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty efficient way to fix this:

Copy the `/vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`-file to `app/design/YourName/YourTheme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and replace the code inside `updateBaseImage()` (line ~1152) with the following:

```
updateBaseImage: function (images, context, isInProductView, eventName) {
    var gallery = context.find(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).data('gallery');

    if (eventName === undefined && gallery !== undefined) {
        this.processUpdateBaseImage(images, context, isInProductView, gallery);
    } else {
        context.find(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).on('gallery:loaded', function (loadedGallery) {
            loadedGallery = context.find(this.options.mediaGallerySelector).data('gallery');
            this.processUpdateBaseImage(images, context, isInProductView, loadedGallery);
        }.bind(this));
    }
},
```

The trick is: this method doesn't wait for the gallery to be fully loaded, while this event (`gallery:loaded`) is readily available. By adding this to the method, it works fine.

I just hope that the Magento Dev's pick up on this and implement this in the core-code.